# Python docx Replacer keeping style

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I can’t figure out how to save the Word style settings when replacing text (font, boldness, etc.).
Reviewed similar articles - did not help
I am using the library: docx-python

Git(code + word docx): https://github.com/AlpacaHD/test.git

I tried this, but it didn't help much.

```
# style = Document.styles\['Normal'\]
# font = style.font
# font.name = 'Times New Roman'
```

I need to somehow "drive" the code with the fonts, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to work at the `Run` level:

> Assigning text to [Run.text] ... Any existing run content is replaced. Run **formatting is preserved**.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run.text

> Assigning text to [Paragraph.text] causes all existing paragraph content to be replaced with a single run containing the assigned text... Paragraph-level formatting, such as style, is preserved. **All run-level formatting, such as bold or italic, is removed**.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.text

```py
def find_replace(paragraph_keyword, draft_keyword, paragraph):
    if paragraph_keyword in paragraph.text:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if paragraph_keyword in run.text:
                run.text = run.text.replace(paragraph_keyword, draft_keyword)
```